# scala lift: How to submit ajaxbutton add and delete

Tags: ajax, scala, submit, lift

I have two list and save button in my edit page.

The left list is a total area list with ajaxbutton of add in each row,
and the right list is a selected area list with ajaxbutton of delete in each row.

The operation is as follows:

1. When the add button of left list is clicked, the selected area will be added to the end of the right list and displayed.
2. When the delete button of right list is clicked, confirm message will be displayed, and if OK is clicked, the selected area will be deleted from the right list.
3. When the save button is clicked, the selected area list will be saved to database.

my source is as follows:

```
// Left list
def showTotalArea: CssBindFunc = {
    ".totalArea *" #> totalAreaList.map(values => 
        ".areaImage [src]" #> values(6) &
        ".areaName *" #> values(4) &
        ".areaComment *" #> values(5) &
        ".copy" #> ajaxButton(S.?("add"), () => doCopy(values(1), "new")) 
    )
}

// Right list
def liftForm(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {  
    var areaList = newOrderList.map(values =>{
        <li id={values(1)} class="items currentOrder">
            <table >
                <thead></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="listImage">
                            <img class="areaImage" src={values(6)}/>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <tr><p class="areaName">{values(4)}</p></tr>
                            <tr><p class="areaComment">{values(5)}</p></tr>
                        </td>
                        <td class="listCheck" >
                            {ajaxButton("delete", () => doConfirm(values(1)), "class" -> "button delete")}
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
                    <tr class = "auto">
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="listSelect" >
                            {
                            val it = ajaxRadio[String](radioList, Box.legacyNullTest(values(2)), doRadioChange(values(1), _)).toForm.grouped(4)
                            for(i <- it)yield(<tr>{i.flatMap(y => <td> {y} </td>)}</tr>)
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>})
    areaList1 = areaList.toString   
    SHtml.ajaxForm(
    bind("list",xhtml,"areaList" -> <ul class="sortable">{areaList}</ul>)
    )
}

// save button
def showFormButton = {
    ".post" #> submit("save", doCompose) &
    ".cancel" #> submit("cancel", doCancel) &
    "#result" #> text("", result = _ )
}

// add button
def doCopy(areaId: String, areaType: String): JsCmd = {
    println("+++++++addArea: " + areaId)
    println("+++++++areaType: " + areaType)
    // check
    if (isExist(areaId)) {
        Alert("The selected area is already in the list.")
    } else {
    val addList = selectedList(totalAreaList, areaId)
    newOrderList = newOrderList:::List(addList)
    println("+++++++newOrderList: " + newOrderList)
    JsRaw("alert(’ButtonAdd clicked’);") &
    JsRaw("""$("liftForm").submit();""")            
    }
}

def selectedList(areaList: List[List[String]], areaId: String): List[String] = {
    var returnList: List[String] = Nil 
    areaList.map(values => 
        if (values(1) ==  areaId) {
            returnList = values
        }
    )
    return returnList
}

// delete button
def doConfirm(areaId: String): JsCmd = {
    Confirm("Are you sure to delete?", SHtml.ajaxInvoke(() => doDelete(areaId))._2.cmd)
}
def doDelete(areaId: String): JsCmd = {
    println("+++++++deleteArea: " + areaId)
    newOrderList.map(values => 
        if (values(1) ==  areaId) {
            newOrderList = newOrderList - values
        }
    )
    println("+++++++newOrderList: " + newOrderList)
    JsRaw("""$("liftForm").submit();""")            
}

// save button 
private def doCompose() {
    println("++++++newOrderList: " + newOrderList.toString)
    //save newOrderList to database
}
```

My problem is:

1. when add button is clicked, the selected area is added to the end of newOrderlist,
    but it doesn't display until save button is clicked.
2. When delete button is clicked, the selected area is deleted from newOrderList,
   but it doesn't disappear from display until save button is clicked.

My question is:

```
How to display the operation result without clicking save button?
```

I have read some thread about ajaxbutton and submit, but I could not understand well.
Is there any simple method to solve this problem?

Thanks for any suggestions

james

---

I have tried to use JsCmds.SetHtml(theID, theContent). 
But I don't know how to edit "theContent" of the second parameter. 
Since in my source, it is defined as "def liftForm(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {" and is binded to the html.

How can I call  the founction liftForm which is  binded to the html from scala?

Thank you 
jamesW

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution might be to use `JsCmds.SetHtml` ([doc](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.js.JsCmds%24%24SetHtml)) with the new element to display at its ID in the `doCopy` method. The bruteforce method would be to just replace the complete form with the updated one, but their might be a better way of doing this.

So you would mainly have to add at the end of the method:

```
& JsCmds.SetHtml(theID, theContent)
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I have tried to use JsCmds.SetHtml(theID, theContent). but I don't know how to edit "theContent" of the second parameter. Since in my source, it is defined as "def liftForm(xhtml: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {"

Comment: I see, maybe you can just put what is in your div as the input of `liftForm`. This is a trick but with Ajax, I prefer doing everything on the Scala side.